# Why this function uses a lot of memory?

Tags: perl, memory, binary, unpack

I'm trying to unpack binary vector of 140 Million bits into list.
I'm checking the memory usage of this function, but it looks weird. the memory usage rises to 35GB (GB and not MB). how can I reduce the memory usage?

```
sub bin2list {
    # This sub translates a binary vector to a list of "1","0" 
    my $vector = shift;
    my @unpacked = split //, (unpack "B*", $vector );
    return @unpacked;

}
```

Comment: Perl scalar needs [several bytes](http://perlmaven.com/how-much-memory-do-perl-variables-use). Why do you need to unpack the vector?

Comment: I'm talking about 35GB, several bytes is nothing.. I need it from several reasons and I can't change it. the main problem for me is the size of '@unpacked' array!

Comment: You copying on 1st line of function. Copying on 2nd. Returning copy. Its highly ineffective high-level code, so memory usage is the cost. Describe what exactly you cannot change and probably we can find workaround.

Comment: I need the binary file in an array of "0" and "1". I can't the returned value. what I cant tell that $vector size is ~600MB (thats OK), and while running this line "my @unpacked = split //, (unpack "B*", $vector );", memory usage raises to 35GB. I need to reduce this.

Comment: [illguts](http://search.cpan.org/dist/illguts/) has information about the format of scalarss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scalars contain a lot of information.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump("0")'
SV = PV(0x42a8330) at 0x42c57b8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,READONLY,pPOK)
  PV = 0x42ce670 "0"\0
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 16
```

In order to keep them as small as possible, a scalar consists of two memory blocks<sup>[1]</sup>, a fixed-sized head, and a body that can be "upgraded" to contain more information.

The smallest type of scalar that can contain a string (such as the ones returned by `split`) is a `SVt_PV`. (It's usually called `PV`, but `PV` can also refer to the name of the field that points to the string buffer, so I'll go with the name of the constant.)

[image: SVt_PV]

The first block is the head.

- `ANY` is a pointer to the body.
- `REFCNT` is a reference count that allows Perl to know when the scalar can be deallocated.
- `FLAGS` contains information about what the scalar actually contains. (e.g. `SVf_POK` means the scalar contains a string.)
- `TYPE` contains information the type of scalar (what kind of information it *can* contain.)
- For an `SVt_PV`, the last field points to the string buffer.

The second block is the body. The body of an `SVt_PV` has the following fields:

- `STASH` is not used in the scalars in question since they're not objects.
- `MAGIC` is not used for the scalars in question. Magic allows code to be called when the variable is accessed.
- `CUR` is the length of the string in the buffer.
- `LEN` is the length of the string buffer. Perl over-allocates to speed up concatenation.

The block on the right is the string buffer. As you might have noticed, Perl over-allocates. This speeds up concatenation.

Ignore the block on the bottom. It's an alternative to the string buffer format for special strings (e.g. hash keys).

To how much does that add up?

```
$ perl -MDevel::Size=total_size -E'say total_size("0")'
28   # 32-bit Perl
56   # 64-bit Perl
```

That's just for the scalar itself. It doesn't take into the overhead in the memory allocation system of three memory blocks.

---

These scalars are in an array. An array is really just a scalar.

[image: SVt_AV]

So an array has overheard.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Size=total_size -E'say total_size([])'
56   # 32-bit Perl
64   # 64-bit Perl
```

That's an empty array. You have 140 million of the scalars in yours, so it needs a buffer that can contain 140 million pointers. (In this particular case, the array won't be over-allocated, at least.) Each pointer is 4 bytes on a 32-bit system, 8 on a 64.

That brings the total up to:

- 32-bit: 56 + (4 + 28) * 140,000,000 = 4,480,000,056
- 64-bit: 64 + (8 + 56) * 140,000,000 = 8,960,000,064

That doesn't factor in the memory allocation overhead, but it's still very different from the numbers you gave. Why? Well, the scalars returned by `split` are actually different than the scalars inside the array. So for a moment, you actually have 280,000,000 scalars in memory!

---

The rest of the memory is probably held by lexical variables in subs that aren't currently executing. Lexical variables aren't normally freed on scope exit since it's expected that the sub will need the memory the next time it's called. That means `bin2list` continues to use up 140MB of memory after it exits.

---

Footnotes

1. Scalars that are undefined can get away without a body until a value is assigned to them. Scalars that contain only an integer can get away without allocating a memory block for the body by storing the integer in the same field as a `SVt_PV` stores the pointer to the string buffer.

---

The images are from [illguts](http://search.cpan.org/dist/illguts/). They are protected by Copyright.

Answer (score 3):

A single integer value in Perl is going to be stored in an `SVt_IV` or `SVt_UV` scalar, whose size will be four machine-sized words - so on a 32bit machine, 16 bytes. An array of 140 million of those, therefore, is going to consume 2.2 billion bytes, presuming it is densely packed together. Add to that the `SV *` pointers in the `AvARRAY` used to reference them and we're now at 2.8 billion bytes. Now double that, because you copied the array when you returned it, and we're now at 5.6 billion bytes.

That of course was on a 32bit machine - on a 64bit machine we're at double again, so 11.2 billion bytes. This presumes totally dense packing inside the memory - in practice this will be allocated in stages and chunks, so RAM fragmentation will further add to this. I could imagine a total size around the 35 billion byte mark for this. It doesn't sound outlandishly unreasonable.

For a very easy way to massively reduce the memory usage (not to mention CPU time required), rather than returning the array itself as a list, return a reference to it. Then a single reference is returned rather than a huge list of 140 million SVs; this avoids a second copy also.

```
sub bin2list {
    # This sub translates a binary vector to a list of "1","0" 
    my $vector = shift;
    my @unpacked = split //, (unpack "B*", $vector );
    return \@unpacked;
}
```

Comment: tried \@unpacked. less memory indeed, but not much, only 2GB.
is there any way to count number of 1's in binary vector ? this could be a work around.

Comment: @user3787639 From [`perldoc -f unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html): "The following efficiently counts the number of set bits in a bit vector: `$setbits = unpack("%32b*", $selectmask);`"

Comment: Re "A single integer value", yeah, but `split` returns strings, which are even larger.