# Why does nothing appear to happen when I run my code with nested for loops?

Tags: perl

I am trying to use a `for` loop to do a calculation and then push the result onto an array. This is the section of the script that I am trying to do this with:

```
my @deltaX;

for my $one (@protx) {
    for my $two (@lipidx) {
        my $deltadX = $one - $two;
        push @deltaX, $deltadX;
    }
}
print "@deltaX \n";
```

When I do this nothing appears to happen and my computer says that `perl` is running but there is no output or warnings.

When I print the array contents inside the for loop, on the other hand, it appears to work:

```
my @deltaX;

for my $one (@protx) {
    for my $two (@lipidx) {
        my $deltadX = $one - $two;
        push @deltaX, $deltadX;
        print "@deltaX \n"; 
    }
}
```

How can I make this work when the `print` is outside of the outer loop?

Comment: FYI, `$one` and `$two` are terrible variable names. Pick something that describes what is contained in the variable, like `$protein` or `$lipid`.

Comment: Also, indent consistently, what you have is difficult to read.

Comment: If your computer says perl is running, the loops probably haven't yet exhausted all the possible pairs.

Comment: How many elements are in each array? It's probably just taking a long time to iterate through all of them. You will have `size of @protx * size of @lipidx` total iterations, so if either of the arrays is very large, it could take a while. You could also be eating into swap, causing things to slow down.

Comment: There is 2083 elements in the '@protx' and about 32000 elements in the '@lipidx'.

Comment: That works out to 66,656,000 iterations and 66,656,000 scalars pushed onto your array. Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25292727) to another question, the array alone would require roughly 2 GB of memory on a 32-bit system and roughly 4 GB on a 64-bit system.

Comment: So, do you really need to store each result in an array? If you do, perhaps take a look at [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::FAQ#Q:-2.1-What-is-PDL).

Comment: If I recall correctly from your previous questions, you're calculating `d` between various atoms / residues / something or other on biomolecules. It might be beneficial for you to post your full code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as the parts of the last iteration that you posted could be made more efficient in terms of coding style, and probably computation, too.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Most of what you say is valid criticism, but there is very little that is constructive and I believe you are unnecessarily harsh

Comment: @Borodin I'm not sure which criticism you're talking about except perhaps my first two comments. Everything after that is directly related to the problem at hand, so certainly constructive and not at all harsh.

Comment: Those alone constitute 40% of your comments on this question. But it is a general notion about your comments, and I am mentioning it only now because of what you have said regarding this same OP's last two questions.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for the feedback. I disagree that my comments are not constructive; even if not directly related to the cause of an issue, I think comments about coding style are important for inexperienced programmers; similarly, I think comments about making SO questions legible are equally important for inexperienced SO users. As for harsh, I can understand how many of my comments could be taken that way since they are often terse; I am only trying to help, so I hope my message isn't being lost because of that. Perhaps I should soften them up and ignore minor issues with beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reassure you that your code is running and actually *doing* something, you can print some progress dots. This example prints a dot every time 10,000 items are pushed to the array, and starts a newline every 100 dots.

```
my @deltaX;

for my $one (@protx) {
    for my $two (@lipidx) {
        my $deltadX = $one - $two;
        push @deltaX, $deltadX;

        print '.' unless @deltaX % 10_000;
        print "\n" unless @deltaX % 1_000_000;
    }
}
print "@deltaX \n";
```

Comment: Nice, this is a cool idea. I see now that my script is running so it must be the size of the data.

Comment: It's a fairly standard debugging technique, but I thought you were unlikely to be aware of it. I'm afraid you have to expect some fire as you are posting on a site for professional programmers who take most things that are new to you for granted.